# GCP Redmine Click To Deploy Sign In as Administrator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redmine

How do you sign in as administrator for GCP Redmine Click to Deploy? Alternatively/additionally, where is the install directory for redmine there so I can mess with users from shell?

The site (https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/click-to-deploy-images/redmine?filter=category:developer-tools&filter=solution-type:vm&filter=price:free&id=58997e72-6583-4ada-abb1-5b470767502b) doesn't have any documentation, and the default username for redmine (admin, password admin) didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's also a [Bitnami Redmine](https://bitnami.com/stack/redmine/cloud/google), where the username is `user`

... and the password can be retrieved via [Deployment Manager](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/get-started/find-credentials/).

For the "Click to Deploy" version, it might also be available there.